# How to get face normal from a mesh loop?

Tags: scripting

I'm iterating through the loops of my mesh and would like to get the face it is attached to (so I can get the face's normal).  I'm looking specifically for the face normal, not the vertex or loop normals.  The docs provide information for finding the associated vertex, but I can't find anything to get the face index.  Is there a way to do this?

```
    for obj in ctx.selected_objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            mesh = obj.data
            for l in mesh.loops:
                v = mesh.vertices[l.vertex_index]
                #looking for face here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Loop the faces**

Suggest this is easier to loop the faces and get the loop indices.

```
for f in mesh.polygons:
    print(f.index, f.loop_indices)
```

default cube

```
0 range(0, 4)
1 range(4, 8)
2 range(8, 12)
3 range(12, 16)
4 range(16, 20)
5 range(20, 24)
```